# netsuite site navigation setup

Tags: web, navigation, netsuite

Trying this again.
First of all, I apologize for my ignorance-I have never used Netsuite before. I recently started at a company that has been using Netsuite. Their site is already set up and in my job I have to edit the site on a daily basis. The hardest thing I have discovered so far is the lack of instructional information online for Netsuite and the organization. I am trying to change out or delete an rollover image on the side navigation bar. I can find all of the images for the initial navigation and their corresponding rollover image, but cannot find any of the subcategory images that come off these. I cannot find where these are set up either in Netsuite.

If I delete the image, will it disappear from the navigation bar or cause an error?

I've tried looking through the source code of the home page, but no luck there. Any suggestions on how to figure this out on a site already set up?

Comment: I remember this question, but when I go to http://www.jlsmithco.com/TONE-HOLE-TOOLS that page does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for looking, eliseobeltran.  Yes, that is my problem. I deleted the category for Tools--Tone Holes but cannot figure out how to take the Tone Holes button off the side navigation. I cannot find the image anywhere to delete it.